# Convertir de fecha string en español a ingles con formato datetime

Tags: php, datetime, formato

en una aplicación es mandatario mostrar las fechas en español pero se deben guardar en la base de datos en ingles de la siguiente forma, una fecha en formato: `2017-Ago-31` o (2017-Ago-30 00:00:00 español esta viene del plugging Datepicker. y quiero convertirla al formato `2017-08-31` numerico en ingles

al intentarlo con el codigo:

```
$date    = new DateTime($date);
$newdate = '';
$newdate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

me da error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2017-Ago-31) at position 4 (-): Unexpected character
```

intente usando:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US");
```

pero no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de una forma simple asi:

```
$months = [
    'Ago' => 'Aug'
];
$date = str_replace(array_keys($months), $months, '2017-Ago-31');
$newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-M-d', $date);
echo $newdate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Coloca los meses que correspondan en el array y listo.

Comment: gracias lo probare

Comment: separado por coma los meses cierto?